# Converting Strings to Hex/ByteArray VB

Tags: vb.net, string, hex, arrays

I'm currently working on project where I am required to take a simple string of characters:

```
string ("Example")
```

and convert to an array of hex bytes:

```
HexByteArray(45 ,78 ,61 ,6d ,70 ,6c ,65)
```

in VBA I achieved this using strconv:

```
bytes = StrConv(id, vbFromUnicode)
```

Struggling to find equivalent functionality in VB, so far I have managed to create an integer equivalent using the Hex() function but as mentioned I need to store each characters hex equivalent within a byte array. Probably a simple solution, all help appreciated!

Comment: `I have managed to create an integer equivalent using Hex()` The legacy VB `Hex()` function returns strings, not integers.  The underlying value is the same whether you use hex notation or not

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f480a85s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Byte Array is enough I think... The hex is just the display

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub GetHexString(Value As String)
    Dim Bytes() As Byte = Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Value)

    ' StringBuilder Capacity for 2 characters plus space per byte
    With New StringBuilder(Bytes.Length * 3)
        For Each B As Byte In Bytes
            ' note the trailing space in the format
            .AppendFormat("{0:x2} ", B)
        Next

        Debug.Print(.ToString.Trim)

        ' If you want an array of strings, split on the spaces
        Dim HexString() As String = Split(.ToString.Trim, " ")
    End With
End Sub
```

Output of GetHexString("Example"):

```
45 78 61 6d 70 6c 65
```